# Android javacv FFmpeg redundant so files

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I am using javacv for adding FFmpeg to my android projecst. The only import I use are:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
```

But I have huge list of so files that I added to my projects that just add weight to my projects. I do not know witch files are neede and witch redundant:

```
libavcodec.so
libavdevice.so
libavfilter.so
libavformat.so
libavutil.so
libjniARToolKitPlus.so
libjniavcodec.so
libjniavdevice.so
libjniavfilter.so
libjniavformat.so
libjniavutil.so
libjnicvkernels.so
libjniopencv_calib3d.so
libjniopencv_contrib.so
libjniopencv_core.so
libjniopencv_features2d.so
libjniopencv_flann.so
libjniopencv_highgui.so
libjniopencv_imgproc.so
libjniopencv_legacy.so
libjniopencv_ml.so
libjniopencv_nonfree.so
libjniopencv_objdetect.so
libjniopencv_photo.so
libjniopencv_stitching.so
libjniopencv_video.so
libjniopencv_videostab.so
libjnipostproc.so
libjniswresample.so
libjniswscale.so
libopencv_calib3d.so
libopencv_contrib.so
libopencv_core.so
libopencv_features2d.so
libopencv_flann.so
libopencv_gpu.so
libopencv_highgui.so
libopencv_imgproc.so
libopencv_info.so
libopencv_legacy.so
libopencv_ml.so
libopencv_nonfree.so
libopencv_objdetect.so
libopencv_photo.so
libopencv_stitching.so
libopencv_video.so
libopencv_videostab.so
libpostproc.so
libswresample.so
libswscale.so
libtbb.so
```